# Bird of paradise not healthy

Tags: houseplants

I live in the UK and have a Bird of Paradise plant that has not been doing too well for just under a year now.

Currently, all the leaves have curled in at the edges and have dried up and gone brown on the edges.  Some leaves have died, some have gone yellow/brown others are still green.  I have had to support the plant with canes as it started falling over.  See photos below.

I have tried:

- Bright room (light meter reading 800 Lux)
- Less bright room (light meter reading 200 Lux)
- Grow light to boost lighting
- Watering less (moisture meter saying moist/dry)
- Watering more (moisture meter saying wet/moist)
- Warmer rooms (18 degrees Celsius)
- Cooler rooms (14/15 degrees Celsius)

Any ideas what is wrong with my plant?

[image: leaf close up]

[image: full plant and pot]

[image: close up of stems and canes]

[image: top view of plant]

[image: curled leaf]

Answer (score 2):

> Warmer rooms (18 degrees Celsius)

That might be the problem (and most people outside of the UK would not consider 18°C to be "warmer" :-).

> Average indoor temperatures of 65-80°F are best for the Bird of Paradise.
>
> — [Bird of Paradise 101: How to Care for Bird of Paradise Plants](https://bloomscape.com/plant-care-guide/bird-of-paradise/#:%7E:text=The%20Bird%20of%20Paradise%20prefers,you%20notice%20crispy%20leaf%20edges.&text=Average%20indoor%20temperatures%20of%2065,for%20the%20Bird%20of%20Paradise.&text=During%20spring%20and%20summer%2C%20fertilize,with%20a%20general%20purpose%20fertilizer.)

That's about 18–25°C, so you're right at the low end, and I expect it gets even colder at night.

Comment: The site linked to above contains a "Common Issues" link; one of those issues is the OP's question: https://bloomscape.com/common-issue/why-are-the-leaves-on-my-bird-of-paradise-dry-and-curling/.  Nice find, Ray. +1

Comment: I will try increasing the heating in the room with the plant to 21°C and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a heat vent I see in the first picture? Many plants won't tolerate being in the breeze from a heat vent. Even tropical plants you might expect to enjoy hot breezes. The mark on the attached picture is what I was looking at.

If it is, you have some possible choices.

- Move the plant to a window not near a heat vent.
- Put a diffuser on the vent to direct the air flow away from the plant.
- Put in some kind of barrier between the plant and the heat vent to keep the air flow off the plant.

[image]

Comment: I'd worry about a draft from that window, too, especially if in the UK, which isn't known for its well-sealed double-glazed windows.

Comment: It's a blind that is rolled up, not a vent of any kind.  The window frames are not perfectly sealed so there could be a draft coming through.